# Error getting access token for service account while uploading to GCS bucket after few hours of successful uploading

Tags: google-cloud-platform, upload, access-token

I had set up the env variable

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/absolute/path/to/json/
```

and trying to upload using DEFAULT instance of the client

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);
BlobInfo blobInfo = storage.create(BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName, fileName)
                .setAcl(new ArrayList(
                        Arrays.asList(Acl.of(User.ofAllUsers(), com.google.cloud.storage.Acl.Role.READER))))
                .build(), file);

fileURL = blobInfo.getMediaLink();
```

and with this I'm getting error:

> Error uploading file (file.pdf) to GCS, error message is Error getting access token for service account: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

While trying to upload with gsutil, I was able to upload the file. But not with java application.

Comment: This is a generic error that means something is wrong with things like keystores, passwords, certificates, etc. Are you setting any command-line switches? The more details the easier to help you.

Comment: i didnt have any command line  switch, is there a way if I can figure this (command-line switches) out?

List of stack trace is as:com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Error getting access token for service account: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:360)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:165)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:151)

Comment: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: excess private key
        at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:325)

Comment: Please put your stack traces into your question. They are not readable in comments without a lot of effort.

Comment: i tried but not able to put complete stack trace in question